# Javascript Filter Array of Objects by Dynamic Key

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I'm starting with an array of objects, such as

```
const data = [
  {
    data1: 124,
    data2: 5332,
    data3: 12,
  },
  {
    data1: 642,
    data2: 5,
    data3: 798,
  }
];
```

I would like to filter the array of objects down to just the "data2" key, like this...

```
[
  {
    data2: 5332
  },
  {
    data2: 5,
  }
]
```

I tried using the `filter` method and several callback variants like:

```
const key = "data2";
const filtered = data.filter((d) => Object.keys(d.data) === key);
```

I know I could use `data.forEach` but was wondering if there is any way to accomplish this using `filter`.

Comment: You want `map` not `filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
const filtered = data.map((d) => ({
  [key]: d[key]
}));
```

Working snippet:

```js
const data = [{
    data1: 124,
    data2: 5332,
    data3: 12,
  },
  {
    data1: 642,
    data2: 5,
    data3: 798,
  }
]

const key = "data2";
const filtered = data.map((d) => ({
  [key]: d[key]
}));

console.log(filtered);
```